# Symfony Value of a SELECT

Tags: symfony

I have a Select which get a list of string, but i need to insert in database their ID, not their name.
I work under symfony 4.2
In my Form, i use this (which works):

```html
    $builder
        ->add('cours', EntityType::class, array(
          'class' => Cours::class,
          'label' => false,
          'placeholder' => 'Cours',
          'required' => true,
          'choice_label' => 'nomUe',
          'choices' => $formation->getCours(),
          'attr' => array('class' => 'custom-select')
        ))
```

I looked the documentation and i want to insert something like that

```html
          'choice_value' =>  $formation->getId(),
```

But that gives me an error like :
[image]

And idea? Thank you!

Comment: `choice_value`'s value is something that describes how to retrieve the value of a choice. for example `'id'` (which the property accessor will use to call `getId` on each course.

Answer (score 0):

in fact you have probably redefined the __toString method in your Class entity .... that's why you have the name in visual in the form ... but in the database it will record the ID of your entity.

so you have to remove the line choices in your form ... so in the end your form should look like this:

```
    $builder
        ->add('cours', EntityType::class, array(
          'class' => Cours::class,
          'label' => false,
          'placeholder' => 'Cours',
          'required' => true,
          'choice_label' => 'nomUe',
          'attr' => array('class' => 'custom-select')
        ))
```

However ... I imagine that your __toString method which is in the Class entity looks like this :

```
public function __toString()
    {
      return $this -> getName() ;
    }
```

so, if you prefer to have the Id rather than the name of the entity in the form, you'll have to display it:

```
public function __toString()
    {
      return  (String) $this -> getId() ;
    }
```